# jQuery ready function doesn't work in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm using jQuery at WordPress (@the HOME page) and the ready function doesn't work for me. I have a index.php which is including (php) a header, footer and a sidebar. I tested this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      alert ("test text");
   });
</script>
```

The alert (with the text `"test text"`) is just not popping up immediately! It's only popping up after my sidebar has been loaded. This means while I'm seeing the index page (sidebar is not loaded yet) I have to wait a few seconds until the sidebar has finished loading, and only then the jQuery code is executed: the alert is popping up. So the ready function just wont work.
Can anybody tell me why and how I can solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 64):

within the WordPress environment, use this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    // now you can use jQuery code here with $ shortcut formatting
    // this executes immediately - before the page is finished loading
});


jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // now you can use jQuery code here with $ shortcut formatting
    // this will execute after the document is fully loaded
    // anything that interacts with your html should go here
});
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you!!! I spent hours trying to figure out why my jQuery wasn't working!

Comment: As an aside: this does answer the generic title of the question, *"jQuery ready function doesnt work in wordpress"*, but does not solve *"It's only popping up after my sitebar has been loaded"*.

Answer (score 2):

The alert is popping up after the sidebar is loaded because ready() is supposed to be executed AFTER the whole page is done loading.

Answer (score 1):

> The alert (with the text "test text") is just not popping up immediately! It's only popping up after my sitebar has been loaded.

That's exactly [the advantage](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Launching_Code_on_Document_Ready) of using `ready`. When you want it to popup right away, simply do

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert ("test text");
</script>
```