# JQuery function fails to work in Wordpress 3.1.2

Tags: jquery, wordpress

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(document)')
```

I know there is one other topic with a similar issue, but trying the solutions in there didn't resolve the problem.

I'm using WordPress 3.1.2 and I'm trying to get it to load a page, but something in WordPress or what I'm typing doesn't seem to let it work.

```
<div id=test>
 <b>Great scott</B>
</div>

<div id=recall>
  <b>see you at the party</b>
</div>
<script src=jquery.js>
</script>

<script>
  $(#test).load(search.php);
</script>
```

That's the code I'm trying to use, it works on a different WP site I worked on, creating the prototype so to speak.

The problem seems to come from pointing it to the jQuery file because not even alerts work. However, when I take out the `src` the alerts appear as normal.

I also used the jQuery's tutorial on jQuery's website to make sure the jQuery file itself was working and that the page ran the jQuery on there perfectly.

I've tried using `JQuery()` instead of `$()`, but when I tried that, `search.php` still doesn't load and there is no error produced in the error log either (I've been using Firefox to test it)

I also tried wrapping it in a function like similar questions have suggestion but that flags up either the same error or no error at all.

Is there a way to fix this or work around this?

Comment: Use jQuery noConflict http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery ready function doesnt work in wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327085/jquery-ready-function-doesnt-work-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around the #test:

```
$('#test').load(search.php);
```

Undefined means the selectors hasn't found anything.

For more about jQuery selectors, look here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors

When debugging - it can help to use firebug in firefox, or the developer console in chrome... and you can type in the javascript directly to see if it runs, or even something like **$('#test')** to see what is being selected.

Comment: Poo that is mistake on my part, when putting this up I was having some trouble formatting the code to display properly. That part does have quotes around it: `$('#test').load('search.php');`

Comment: Hmmm... It could be something with the URL to your search.php... I'm assuming it's on same server, and in yoursite.com/search.php? Are you using firebug or something equivalent... can you see an error in the network communications?

Comment: It seems to be a url issue. I was checking the network tab as you said and the path seems to be _www.website.com/currentpage/jquery.js_ Which is really odd because wordpress doesn't create static pages like that. I just tried doing the method I have seen used to go back a folder .../ but instad it just added it onto the URL instead. I have solved it now though but I think I've done it the clunky way, I've typed out the whole URL so it looks like this _www.www.website.com/jquery.js_ I've also updated the other file references. Thanks 4 the firebug tip. BTW do you knw a shrt hnd way of doing it?

Comment: I checked a wordpress theme I'm using that has jQuery, and it does use absolute paths, which make sense to me since the url's are dynamically generated.  You might post a new question to see if a guru out there knows a better way!

Answer (score 0):

Load the function after the DOM is loaded:

```
 <div id="test">
   <b>Great scott</B>
 </div>

 <div id="recall">
  <b>see you at the party</b>
 </div>
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>

 <script>
 $(function(){
     $("#test").load("search.php");
  });
 </script>
```